# Handling errors from PHP OOP to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP in PHP but I'm having some troubles at the moment. Whenever method is executed i don't know what value should i return to be able to handle it with jQuery in both cases - true and false. For example, in Pick_data() if false i want to get value like: "Fill in all fields" and most important, to be able to display it for user using jQuery or Ajax. I will leave code down below. Places commented ,,//I NEED HELP HERE" is my problem. I'm not asking you to write whole code and just need reference to information how can i deal with it. I would appreciate that because i'm completely lost. I will leave code down below(it's working fine expect my problem). Thanks!

```
<?php 

require ('db_connect.php');

Class Registration {

public $username, $password;


public function Pick_data() {

    if (isset ($_POST['username']) && isset ($_POST['password'])) {

$this->username = trim($_POST['username']);
$this->password = trim($_POST['password']);

} //end of if isset
    if (!empty($this->username) && !empty($this->password) ) {

return true;//NEED HELP HERE

} //end of is empty 
else //NEED HELP HERE
} //end of Pick_data

public function Username_equivalent_check() {

$find_username_equivalent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE Username='".$this->username."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($find_username_equivalent) == 0) {

    return true;//NEED HELP HERE

} //end of  (mysql_num_rows)
else //NEED HELP HERE
} //end of Username_equivalent_check

public function Input_data() {

$input_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO websiteusers (Username, Password) 
VALUES ('$this->username','$this->password')");

if ($input_user) {

return true; //NEED HELP HERE

}//end of inputing new user data
else //NEED HELP HERE
} //end of input_data

} //end of class

$var = new Registration;
$var->Pick_data();
$var->Username_equivalent_check();
$var->Input_data(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here are a few suggestions:

When an error occurs, you do not just want to return a true/false result, but you want to return a text message. That text message can then be displayed (or can be passed to jQuery or whatever). Since you are a beginner, I would say just change your functions to return a string value (the actual error message text) instead of returning just false in case of an error. Something like this:

```
public function Pick_data() {
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) $this->username = trim($_POST['username']);
    if (empty($this->username)) return 'User name must be specified.';
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) $this->password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if (empty($this->password)) return 'Password must be specified.'; 
    return true;
}
```

As you can see above, your Pick_data function will return with an error message (a string value) if either one of the required fields were empty. It will only return true if there were no errors.

Then when you call this function, you must check its return value:

```
$var = new Registration;
$result = $var->Pick_data();
if ($result !== true) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $result; // This gets executed when Pick_data returned an error message
} else {
    // This gets executed when Pick_data returned true, so only here you should continue:
    $result = $var->Username_equivalent_check();
    // you must check here the $result variable again as it now contains the return value of your Username_equivalent_check function
    // ...and so on

}
```

If you must do a lot of checks one after the other, you'll end up with a lot of nested if / else statements. Which is not so great. But as a beginner programmer you need to learn that you should almost always need to check the return value of each(!) function you call!

A more advanced solution is to use a try / catch block, something like this:

```
try {
    $var = new Registration;
    $var->Pick_data();
    $var->Username_equivalent_check();
    $var->Input_data();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Get the error message:
    $error_msg = $e->getMessage();
    // and print it out
    echo 'Error: ' . $error_msg;
}
```

To make the above try / catch block work, you must(!) also change your functions to throw an exception (error) when something goes wrong, something like this:

```
public function Pick_data() {
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) $this->username = trim($_POST['username']);
    if (empty($this->username)) throw new Exception('User name must be specified.');
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) $this->password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if (empty($this->password)) throw new Exception('Password must be specified.'); 
}
```

Using try / catch blocks are much more elegant because you do not end up with a lot of nested if / else statements. Note: when an exception is thrown while the program is running within a try / catch block the program execution stops there immediately and the catch block gets executed.

I think now you have a better idea on how to handle error events in PHP.

If you want to display the error message in the user's web browser with jQuery then you must pass the error message from the server which runs your PHP code to the browser which can only run javascript (jQuery is written in javascript). Nowadays forms are being submitted from the browser to the server via an Ajax call. It looks something like this: First the form gets being displayed in the browser (PHP sends the page containing the form to the browser when the user visits your page). The user fills the form and when hitting the Submit button javascript takes over and sends the form data to the server. This way the user is still on the same page, in other words the page does not get reloaded. When your server receives the Ajax request from the javascript code running in the browser, it does the actual processing, in your example checks the values of the form fields, etc. Finally the server sends the results back usually as a JSON object to the browser, to the calling javascript program. Then the results can be displayed by the javascript code running in the user's browser. So for what you want to do you need to learn both PHP and javascript programming and you need to learn using jQuery and the JSON format as well.

Comment: Your's examples are extremely clear and informative. I already used your examples, finally i can avoid tons of else/if statements. Still, I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to catch different exceptions. For example, one block for invalid input data from forms, another for MySql errors. In case i will have 2 errors,but from different sections.